# How to prevent duplicate entry in google sheets per row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So using the example data below, how can I prevent a duplicate entry with an informative message. The duplicate entry should be based on the row and not the whole sheet.

[image]

So, if I was to add a second column named Colour2, and I added 'Blue' for Bob. I want it to prevent the entry with a suitable message. But I dont want it to prevent the entry of 'Blue' for Alex as he hasnt chosen Blue yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that the real-life implementation you have in mind will be more complex than the sample. But for your sample as given:

Add header "Colour2" into Column C.

Select cell C2.

Choose "Data" from the top menu, then choose "Data validation" from the drop-down menu.

When the Data Validation dialog opens, append ":C" to the end of the range showing in the top text box beside "Cell range:"

Click the drop-down next to "Criteria:" and choose "Custom formula is" from the bottom of that list.

In the textbox beside "Custom formula is," enter this formula: `=COUNTIF(B2:C2,B2)<2`

Beside "On invalid data:" check "Reject input."

Check the box beside "Appearance:", delete the technical language in that text box, and enter something that will serve as *both* a short preemptive tip and an explanation if a duplicate is entered (e.g., "Avoid duplicate entries").

Click the blue "Save" button.

---

Another "gentler" approach might be to use conditional formatting. It won't prevent duplicate input, but it will certainly let you know that you need to change duplicates to something else:

Add header "Colour2" into Column C.

Select cell C2.

Choose "Format" from the top menu, then choose "Conditional formatting" from the drop-down menu.

When the Conditional Formatting dialog opens, append ":C" to the end of the range showing in the text box below "Apply to range."

Click the drop-down below "Format cells if" and choose "Custom formula is" from the bottom of that list.

In the textbox below "Custom formula is," enter this formula: `=COUNTIF(B2:C2,B2)>1`

Click the mint green button that says "Default" under "Formatting style." Select the "123" in red font on a white background. Click the strikethrough button below that (the icon is a small "S" with a line through it).

Click the blue "Done" button, then close the Conditional Formatting dialog by clicking the "X" in the top right corner.

Now, any time a duplicate is entered, the text will turn red with a line through it — clear indication that it should be changed.